# Using Controls and Components of Visual Studio in my application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, components

I'm currently trying to find out, if (also legally) I can use the components of Visual Studio in my applications. I don't mean the controls that are delivered to create my application, like a Button.

I mean the PropertyGrid, the Text Editor, etc, that VS also uses internally in the VS application itself.

The PropertyGrid would be especially interesting because the old winforms PropertyGrid can only be used with WindowsFormsHost, but using the old technolgy is also causing troubles when using windows with transparency, etc.

My questions are:

1. Am I allowed to do it?
2. Can you please provide me with an example of how to do that?

Comment: ok, but what is your question?

Comment: Alright, the question is, 1.) am I allowed to do it? 2.) How do I do it?